# Python BlueZ Mesh

Tags: python, linux, bluez, bluetooth-mesh

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with the latest BlueZ (5.54) stack.
My goal is to make a Python script which collects different sensor data (Air Quality and Temperature) via Bluetooth Mesh.
I was googling many articles and forums but could not decide which one is the best solution.

Tried to find a suitable Python library like PyBluez but as I know it is not under active developement (no mesh).

Another solution is to use the DBus API.

- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/test-mesh
- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mesh-api.txt

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with the D-Bus API as this seems to be the [focus of the developers](https://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&m=156447001828284&w=2)

There are a number of D-Bus bindings for Python depending what you are looking for. Many of them are listed at: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DbusExamples

And there are others, such as [dbussy](https://github.com/ldo/dbussy), which are based around the asyncio event loop which has been used for this example: https://github.com/SilvairGit/bluetooth-meshd-example/blob/master/meshd_example/client.py